# "class" message sent to superclass in Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, superclass

Let us consider following classes:

```
Object subclass: Sup [].

Sup subclass: Sub [ print_superclass [ super class printOn: stdout. ] ].
```

When I try to run `print_superclass` method on Sub I get

```
> Sub new print_superclass.
Sub
```

I expected here to get `Sup` because the `class` call was moved back to the superclass of `Sub` which is `Sup`. Why does it behave like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because super is a pseudo-variable pointing to the receiver of the message. 
Super and self point to the same object and have the same identity.

```
super == self ---> true
```

The difference between them is that *super* tells the message lookup to start searching the next in the method dictionary "above" that containing the method.

The definition is confusing, but in this case, super only says that the method search for #class does not start in **Sub** methods, but in **Sup** methods. However, it does not have effect because #class is defined in a higher level of the hierarchy and its implementation refers to the class of the receiver, that is an instance of Sub

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you get is the expected one. The key is in the semantics of `super`. Let's see some examples before analyzing your case:

**Example 1**

```
ClassA         "implements msg"
  ClassB       "implements msg"
    ClassC     "implements msg"
```

This means that the inherited version of `msg` is overridden in `ClassB` and `ClassC`. In this case

```
super msg       "sent from ClassC invokes ClassB >> msg"
super msg       "sent from ClassB invokes ClassA >> msg"
super msg       "sent from ClassA will signal MessageNotUnderstood"
```

(I'm assuming `msg` is not implemented above `ClassA`)

**Example 2**

```
ClassA         "implements msg"
  ClassB       "does not implement msg"
    ClassC     "implements msg"
```

Then

```
super msg       "sent from ClassC invokes ClassA >> msg"
super msg       "sent from ClassB invokes ClassA >> msg"
```

**Example 3**

```
ClassA         "implements msg"
  ClassB       "does not implement msg"
    ClassC     "does not implement msg"
```

Here

```
super msg       "sent from ClassC invokes ClassA >> msg"
super msg       "sent from ClassB invokes ClassA >> msg"
```

So, the semantics of `super` is: *start the lookup in my superclass*.

**Your case**

Yo have

```
Object         "implements class"
  Sup          "does not implement class"
    Sub        "does not implement class"
```

Therefore, when you send `super class` from `Sub` it will invoke `Object >> class`, right? Which is the same as sending `self class` (because `class` is not implemented in `Sub`), which is `Sub`. And since `Sub new print_superclass` sends `super class` from `Sub`, you get `Sub`.